# Form submit in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm new to opencart. I have to write a custom Log-in form for users. Then i design a small code for log-in form in opencart like below. path is (MyTheme/temlate/auth/Sign.tpl)

```
<form action="<?php echo $Sub; ?>" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name:<Input type="text" name="txtUser">
<br>
Password:<input type="password" name="txtPassword"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

and controller is like (Path is controller/auth/Sign.php)

```
    <?php
    class ControllerAuthSign extends Controller{
        public function index() {
            $data['Sub']=$this->url->link('auth/result','','SSL');

            if(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template'). '/template/auth/sign.tpl')){
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/auth/sign.tpl',$data));
            }
            else{
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/account/login.tpl'));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

when a user submit the form have to navigate to Result page (Path is /auth/result.tpl)

```
    <?php
    echo "Welcome : Mr./Mrs. ".$User;   
?>
<br><p>Your are Loged-In</p>
```

and the controller for Result is.. (Path is /auth/result.php)

```
    <?php
    class ControllerAuthResult extends Controller{
        public function index() {
            $data['User']=$_REQUEST['txtUser'];
            $data['Password']=$_REQUEST['txtPassword'];

            if(isset($data)){
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('auth/sign', '', 'SSL'))
            }
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/auth/result.tp',$data));
        }
    }
?>
```

but the problem is when i click on submit , page navigate to

> http://localhost/opencart/index.php?txtUser=Narayana&txtPassword=narayana

and displayed index page. Can any one help how to navigate to result page...?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<form action="<?php echo $Sub; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name:<Input type="text" name="txtUser">
<br>
Password:<input type="password" name="txtPassword"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Also did you try to echo your `$sub`?

Comment: In the signup controller, how are you declaring $sub? Can you show me the code?

Comment: Thank you 'Ali Zia'.
Yes i did in Sign.tpl.

Comment: Pleasure @NarayanaPusarla